# Выход за пределы массива

Tags: c++, массивы

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[2];
    int b[2];

    cin>>a[0]>>b[0];
    cin>>a[1]>>b[1];
    cin>>a[2]>>b[2];

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<' ';

    }
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Почему выводится ошибка, если я не выхожу за пределы массива?

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack
> around the variable 'a' was corrupted.

Comment: Спасибо! Извините, не знаю, как выбрать ваш ответ в качестве решения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Число в объявлении массива `int a[2];` -- это размер массива, количество его элементов.

Т.е. у Вас доступны 2 элемента, а именно: `a[0]` и `a[1]`.